# different options available for developing language translation app in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have googled and found 2 options. But Google translation API's are paid now. Microsoft has free API's but its not supporting TELUGU and TAMIL languages.

Some of the apps are translating text into these languages

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/type-tamil/69e961a3-b60c-4335-b9c0-a378065eaa8e

Any idea what are the other translation options.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think they are using Bing or google translator.Microsoft provide APIs that can be called with `HTTP` or `SOAP`. Please check this links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872395.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/developers.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136164/Bing-Translator-service-for-Windows-Phone

http://www.jimmycollins.org/blog/?p=241

http://matthiasshapiro.com/2012/10/09/azure-microsoft-translation-in-windows-phone-the-easy-way/

Or you can use Google translator also see this for more information : http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Google_Translate_in_Windows_Phone

You can use `Multilingual App Toolkit`. But it support specific language like English,French, Korean.
https://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/multilingual-app-toolkit

Comment: Ajay, Thank you so much for the info. Bing translator doesn't support tamil and telugu. I will check the other link you provided. Thank you once again :)